# How to add repository to services with AddTransient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

This is my project structure:

[image: This is mine Project structure]

I want to know how I can add repository to `AddTransient`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IDrinkRepository Implementation>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left the (semi-pseudo) code as is.

You'd use it as follows:

```
services.AddTransient<IDrinkRepository, DrinkRepository>();
```

where `DrinkRepository` is a concrete implementation of `IDrinkRepository`.
Does that answer your question?

Comment: What is DrinkRepository